# Liferay Theme - Velocity - Check if user has custom role

Tags: themes, liferay, velocity, roles

I've been scouring through questions on **SO** for a solution to this without any luck as of yet. I have found some *similar* questions, but no solution.

I'm trying to add some sort of *role check* on login to see if a user has a custom role i've defined. If so. They get the dockbar.

Currently it's checking to see if they're an admin across the entire site. Which is something I don't want to give people. They need to be like a Power User with a specific set of permissions.

The current check is like so:

```
#if ($is_signed_in && $permissionChecker.isOmniadmin())
```

I have seen examples checking for a specific role ID which look like they would work.

Example here:

```
#set($UserLocalServiceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
#if ($UserLocalServiceUtil.hasRoleUser(roleID, $user.getUserId()))
```

The only problem with this approach is I am unsure of what my custom roles ID is and how I go about getting it..

So

Does anyone know how I can get my custom roles ID?

**OR**

Is there some sort of `.getRoleName` selector that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this method could help you to complete the code.

Is it possible to have Role by name (and the name could be stored & configured by theme settings)

```
#set($RoleLocalServiceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService"))
#set ($role = $RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(roleName, $themeDisplay.companyId))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in one method call

```
#set ($roleLocalServiceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService"))

#if  ($roleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRole($user.getUserId(),$user.getCompanyId(), "<YOUR ROLE NAME>", true))
```

Thanks.